# Storing (and querying) python ipaddress data-type in neo4j

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

Using python3 ipaddress module, one can construct ip address objects like

```
addr = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.4.5')
net = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.4.0/24')

if addr in net:
    print ('Address in Network')
```

It's not a far leap to see the benefits of being able to query network information in neo4j

```
match (n:IpAddress)-(r:PartOfNetwork)->(d:Network) where d.name = '192.168.3.0/23') return n
```

Is it possible to make neo4j "**understand**" (not just store as text), ip address/network **logic**?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Neo4j can't understand if IP address/network logic.
The only way for now is to create and store IP address and network nodes, as you mentioned.

If you want to add this logic you can write procedure for Neo4j using Java and extends it's functionality.